# Is there a way to increase SpeechContext limit on google cloud speech?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am looking at their API documentation and it seems we can only add the context per request basis. It seems 500 phrases is not enough and was looking on how we can increase SpeechContext Limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a support request to have your quota raised.